# Program crashes putting pointers into vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

this question has been asked before but I did not understand anything in the answers, even after doing some research. My program crashes when I send a pointer of an object to a vector. This code is what is causing it, specificly where I am adding the projectile to the vector.

```
void WorldManager::spawnProjectile (int x,int y,int speedx,int speedy){
    //LaserBulletProjectile proj(x,y,speedx,speedy);
    Projectile *proj;
    proj = new LaserBulletProjectile(x,y,speedx,speedy);
    projectiles->push_back(proj);
}
```

and the vector

```
std::vector<Projectile * > * projectiles;
```

I have heard about rule of three (and five?) and don't understand. Can somone try to explain this in a way that is beginner friendly? I might be over thinking things :)

Also, after more reading I think this is because of the pointer not being deallocated. I hadn't written this yet, because there hasn't been a chance to in my code yet. (I have not got any of this stuff working yet, I thought I could do that later. Maybe that is the issue.)

Comment: Are you actually allocating the vector (eg `projectiles = new std::vector<Projectile*>`) anywhere?

Comment: Damn it! Why do I always miss the just out of sight problems. Thank you so, so much. I can't believe I missed that! Should I delete question? Thankyou, if you want you can post that as an answer.

Comment: cheers! I've posted it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate the vector:

```
projectiles = new std::vector<Projectile*>;
```

Before you try and add things to it!

Answer (score 1):

The rule of three states that:-

```
If your class needs any of

a copy constructor,
an assignment operator,
or a destructor,
```

defined explictly, then it is likely to need all three of them.